# Disabling the current tab in a bottom navigation controller

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-navigation

I'm using Jetpack Navigation to handle the bottom navigation controller. It works great; however, I am looking for a way to improve the UX.

**Is it possible to disable the tab that the user is currently navigated to?**

I'm able to "spam" the current tab in the bottom navigation, which reloads data & the UI unnecessarily. If this behavior (of re-tapping the current tab) is intended, is there a way to retain the state of the fragment, so that when navigated away & to, it doesn't recreate?

How I handle the bottom navigation:

```
navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(navigation_host_fragment)
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottom_navigation_view, navController)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124538620):

> Feel free to set a `OnNavigationItemReselectedListener`, which takes precedence over the OnNavigationItemSelectedListener set by NavigationUI: [setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView#setonnavigationitemreselectedlistener)

```
bottom_navigation_view.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {
  // Do nothing
}
```

Comment: Amazing, one line of code and everything works AS EXPECTED. Ah, I love android.